# Get parent item and it's all child item from solr searchresultItem

Tags: solr, glass-mapper, sitecore-api

I have a requirement that needs to get particular item along with all child item or some of the child item using template id from solr searchresultitem. Can anyone help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is:

```
var parent = searchResultItem.GetItem();
var children = item.Children.Where(c => c.TemplateID == SOME_TEMPLATE_ID);
```